# How i should pass 2 variables for table.blacklist on kafka

Tags: json, apache-kafka

I am trying to use "PUT" method in json to  an existing kafka connector by trying blacklist two tables.(using postman)

```
{
    "connector.class": "io.confluent.connect.jdbc.JdbcSourceConnector",
    "table.blacklist": ["abc", "def"],
}
```

I tried to pass as a list, also tried dictionary i am getting an  error . Tried passing as a string still same error .

Error:

```
-08-01 02:07:04,627] WARN  (org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler:620)
javax.servlet.ServletException: org.glassfish.jersey.server.ContainerException: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Can not deserialize instance of java.lang.String out of START_ARRAY token
 at [Source: org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.ReaderInterceptorExecutor$UnCloseableInputStream@68885dec; line: 2, column: 68] (through reference chain: java.util.LinkedHashMap["table.blacklist"])
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.serviceImpl(WebComponent.java:489)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:427)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:388)
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me
"table.blacklist": "abc,def",